# ssh command just exits the sesssion

Tags: shell, ssh, terminal, ssh-agent

I have this:

```
ssh -i "alex-kp.pem" 'ec2-user@ec2-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' '

  cd codes/vbe
  eval $(ssh-agent)
  ssh-add -D
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_vbe
'
```

it executes the commands but then just exits the session too, so I return back to my local machine. Anyone know why?

Comment: Hint: Do you expect e.g. `ssh … date` not to exit? After `date` the remote non-interactive shell has nothing more to do and thus it exits.

Comment: yes I expected it to not exit by default. when you type commands in your terminal, does it exit by default? lol

Answer (score 2):

You have provided a command (well, a series of commands) to execute on the remote system. Once that command (those commands) have completed, the session exits. This is defined and should be expected behaviour - see `man ssh`:

> If a command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

A simpler example, which executes `hostname` on the remote system

```
ssh -i alex-kp.pem ec2-user@ec2-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens on the remote side

Local `ssh user@server 'shell_code'` makes the SSH server run something like:

```
"$SHELL" -c 'shell_code'
```

I'm not claiming it's *exactly* like this, but it's certainly close enough to understand what happens. I wrote it as if it was invoked in a shell, so it looks familiar; but in fact there is no shell yet.

A shell invoked this way exits when it reaches the end of the `shell_code`. In your case the code is multi-line, this changes nothing.

Without shell code, e.g. upon plain `ssh user@server`, the SSH server starts something different:

```
"$SHELL" -i
```

Again, I'm not claiming it's *exactly* like this.

A shell invoked this way is an *interactive* shell that prints a prompt and waits for input. It seems this is the behavior you wanted to achieve.

It's the SSH server that deliberately uses one form or the other, depending on the form of local `ssh` invocation. The latter form works well for interactive use and the former form equally well runs some non-interactive shell code remotely, as if it was local. E.g. locally you can do:

```
<data md5sum
```

but if you are missing `md5sum` locally, you can use a remote one:

```
<data ssh user@server md5sum
```

Like local `md5sum` exits after doing its job, `ssh … md5sum` also exits after the remote `md5sum` does its job. Quite useful.

Or you can pipe to a remote file:

```
<data ssh user@server 'cat >copy'
```

and `cat`, the remote shell and the local `ssh` will exit automatically when appropriate.

Or you can ask server the time:

```
ssh user@server date
```

and it will behave like local `date`, it won't put you in an interactive remote shell.

---

#### When interactive shells exit automatically

> I expected it [`ssh … date`] to not exit by default. When you type commands in your terminal, does it exit by default?

It does, really. An interactive shell does exit when it reaches EOF when reading commands. The thing is it doesn't "experience" EOF from the terminal until you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> ([once or twice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/701317/108618)). This is how it works with a terminal; but if you make an interactive shell read from a regular file or from a pipe then it will see EOF exactly when you expect this:

```
{ echo date; echo sleep 5; echo date; } | bash -i
```

and it will exit.

So every shell exits by default when there is truly nothing more to do. Interactive shells allegedly "don't exit" because reading from a terminal is *deliberately* designed not to trigger EOF when there is no input at the moment, with an assumption that input may come any minute. It's about the terminal, not about the shell nor any program in general; I mean e.g. `</etc/fstab cat` exits but plain `cat` reading from a tty can work indefinitely, it's the same story.

---

#### Importance of remote tty

The two ways an SSH server can run a shell differ not only in their forms. Remote interactive commands work well when they use a tty they find local (so it's a tty on the server side, it sits between local `ssh` and the commands); but remote non-interactive commands (like our example `md5sum`) work well when there is no tty allocated. The SSH server allocates a tty or not and it does it automatically (but there are options for `ssh` to explicitly choose if needed: `-t`, `-tt`, `-T`). I think you can get some insight from the following question (and answer) of mine, where I tried to get the best from both at once: *[ssh with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618)*.

---

#### What you can do

It looks you want to get a remote interactive shell that executes some shell code before giving you the first prompt. The easiest way is to put the code into the right startup script (`~/.bashrc` if the shell is Bash) and just `ssh` (without passing any shell code) to an interactive remote shell. It's a permanent solution, not useful if you want to be able to run one-time code on demand and still get a prompt.

To execute shell code on demand you need a contraption like this:

```bash
ssh -t … '
  exec bash --rcfile <(cat <<"EOF"
    # your custom shell code here
    . ~/.bashrc
    # and/or here
EOF
) -i'
```

This assumes the shell to be started by the SSH server understands `<(…)` (Bash does understand) and the shell you want as the ultimate interactive shell is Bash.

The SSH server will run a non-interactive shell, still with a tty (because of `-t`). This shell will `exec` to an interactive Bash that will source a custom file instead of `~/.bashrc`. The file will be a pipe from the process substitution and its content will be your custom shell code plus the instruction to source `~/.bashrc` anyway. This way you will make the ultimate shell execute your custom shell code and then give you the prompt.

Note an interactive shell spawned directly by the SSH server would be a login shell, it would source `/etc/profile`. Here neither shell is a login shell. We could run the ultimate shell with `-l`, but it would ignore `--rcfile` then.

However, your *specific* custom shell code sets up things that survive `exec` (they can be inherited in general). This means we can simplify our snippet to:

```bash
ssh -t … '
  cd codes/vbe
  eval $(ssh-agent)
  ssh-add -D
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_vbe
  exec bash -i
'
```

And I think in this case you can add `-l` and make the ultimate Bash a login shell, if this is what you need. Remember that login and non-login shells source different files; the files may source one another (e.g. `~/.bash_profile` may source `~/.bashrc`); [even non-interactive Bash may source `~/.bashrc`](https://superuser.com/a/1616143/432690); and there are two remote shells in sequence, each may source something. It's likely the remote `~/.bashrc` will be sourced two times. Depending on its content side effects may appear.

A very different alternative is to invoke `ssh …` (without shell code) from a local `expect` script. The script should inject the desired shell code and finally let you `interact`. The below quick and dirty example assumes that your remote prompt can be detected by matching `@*:*$` .

```
expect -c '
 spawn ssh -i alex-kp.pem ec2-user@ec2-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
 expect "@*:*$ "
 send "cd codes/vbe\r"
 expect "@*:*$ "
 send "eval \$(ssh-agent)\r"
 expect "@*:*$ "
 send "ssh-add -D\r"
 expect "@*:*$ "
 send "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_vbe\r"
 interact
'
```

I don't know AWS, but in general `ssh-agent` started by `eval $(ssh-agent)` may or may not survive after you disconnect. If it's going to survive then manual cleaning (`ssh-agent -k`) before exiting the remote shell is a good idea.